# Use Python list as input for Matlab function in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, matlab

I have a Matlab function M-file called `func`. This takes a single number as input, and outputs a single number.

I want to use this code in Python, get output in Python, and use that to create visualisations in Python. I'm using `matlab_engine` and I want to run this function for each value from 0.1 to 500.0 (0.1 steps) and record the output for each value in Python.

To do this, I made a numpy array from 0.1 to 500.0, turned it into a list, then converted this list to a Matlab array of data type double. I then tried to use `arrayfun` to call the function with the array `A` as input, but I keep running into errors.

This is my Python code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matlab.engine as me
import matlab as mat

eng = me.start_matlab()

eng.cd(r'/Users/talha/Documents/Sem1/Topics')

array = np.arange(0.1, 500.1, 0.1).tolist()

A = mat.double(array)

x = eng.arrayfun(f,A)
print(x)
```

I get the error: `NameError: name 'func' is not defined`

Right before the end of the function in matlab, I added the line `f = @func`

I also tried

```
x = eng.arrayfun(eng.func,A) print(x)
```

but I get the error `TypeError: unsupported Python data type: matlab.engine.matlabengine.MatlabFunc`

What am I doing wrong here? Is there perhaps a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation for `matlab.engine`, there is no mention of function handles that I could find. This makes me believe that it is not possible to create one directly in Python. `eng.func` is a Python function, calling it causes the MATLAB engine to run the MATLAB function `func`. But `eng.func` is not a MATLAB function handle, it is the name of a Python function.

The MATLAB function [`str2func`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html) creates a function handle from a string representation of the function name. In MATLAB, `str2func('func')` returns the same handle as `@func`. We can call this function from Python to get a MATLAB function handle:

```py
import matlab.engine as me

eng = me.start_matlab()

# ...

f = eng.str2func('func')
x = eng.arrayfun(f, A)
```